# Jobs tab title is dynamically changing, it is for A/B testing or else?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs, top-bar, a-b-testing

There are various number of titles are placed instead of the **Jobs** tab in the top bar.

- Browse Jobs
- Find a Job
- Job Board
- Developer Jobs
- Explore Jobs
- Search Jobs

These are dynamically changing when we are open the Stack Overflow in new browsers.

These dynamic title change is for the [A/B_testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) or something else?

Screenshot for reference:

[image: SO JObs]

Comment: I see "Search Jobs" when I open a private browser window. For what it's worth, I don't like any of these as well as "Jobs". All the other tabs have a one-word description.

Comment: Aren't you also "Browsing Questions" or "Searching Documentation"? Why does "Jobs" need an explanation word before it, while the other tabs seem self explanatory? Also, the current tabs design just separates the different tabs by some space, so I agree with @CodyGray that a one-word description is much clearer.

Comment: I don't like "Jobs" without an explanatory word. It makes me think they are jobs at StackExchange, not jobs in any company.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes, we are currently running a multivariate test on Jobs link text. This is why you see the differences per browser.

Comment: Isn't this actually an A/B/C/D/E (or more) test?  In addition to the 4 above I'm seeing "Explore Jobs".

Comment: I think I need an "A/B block" plugin.

Comment: It's good practice to chose the variation deterministically based on user data (eg using a pseudo random number with the userid as the seed), so that every user sees a consistent treatment, avoiding inconsistent content that leads to confusion and questions like this. You can bet that if this user took the time to ask this question, there are 1000's of users feeling exactly the same that didn't bother.

Comment: @DanNeely yes, it's a multivariate test.

Comment: @Bohemian you're right, but a *large* portion of our user base is anonymous, so we may only fingerprint them by browser and IP address basically. Otherwise we'd have to wait a *lot* longer for our tests to reach statistical significance.

Comment: @Haney Just throwing this out there; I was *trying* to go to the Jobs tab and having the text change actually made it *harder* to get there (since I was scanning for "Jobs" and the tab started with "Browse")

Comment: @Yakk, just add `try{document.getElementById('nav-jobs').textContent = 'Jobs';} catch(e){}` to whatever user script you use on SO pages. Alternately: `var jobs = document.getElementById('nav-jobs');if(jobs){jobs.textContent = 'Jobs';}`

Comment: Note that on my Linux/Firefox system I just see "developer": https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5pQH.png

Comment: @maky I am not just saying UI flux is annoying, but rather all A/B testing would be nice to opt out of...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker - should be sorted now. Can you confirm?

Comment: Yup @oded, looks fine now

Comment: @Yakk I'm pretty sure optional self-selection out of A/B testing would be correlated with variables of interest and hence void the whole purpose of the testing. The only likely case in which it won't be correlated is when either a large chunk of user base decides to opt out (removing any significance), or a really small chunk opts out (and then, why bother)

Comment: @foobar yes, which is why I'd need A/B Block.  Much like adblock gets rid of annoying ads, A/B block stops annoyiny A/B testing.  It would be hard to write.  But experiencing constant psycological experiments for commercial purposes without consent gets old.

Comment: @Yakk Oh right, I forgot that StackExchange just like any other company trashes user experience for no other reason than its own profits - clearly visible from the abundance of advertisement around here.  At its extreme, your argument is the same of those who illegaly share movies: "Much like adblock gets rid of annoying ads, uTorrent stops annoying paying for movies. It's difficult to maintain. But having to permanently pay producers for their products for commercial purposes gets old.

Comment: And as usual, if features of a product are public knowledge, consent stems from consumption. But perhaps it'd be good to put it into TOS, just for the very special kind of users.

Comment: @foobar Sure.  I can write terms of service too!  By reading to the end of this comment, you hereby agree to give me all of your worldly goods.  If you do not wish to agree to this contract, stop reading.  As consideration, here is a funny word: Fuzzbubble.

Comment: @FooBar "trashing user experience" - "one text changes for test purposes" => **WHAT??**

Comment: @Xatenev I totally did not forget the sarcasm tags in that post. /irony

Comment: Looks like it's cutting off "users" now @Oded: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYlic.png

Comment: @Carpetsmoker what Linux distribution do you have? Also what version of Firefox?

Comment: Firefox 54 on Arch Linux @Paweł

Comment: @Carpetsmoker i'm gonna push some fix for this in couple mins. you'll have to wait few hours until build is out.

Answer (score -2):

With Stylish ([Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/), [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en), [Opera](https://addons.opera.com/extensions/details/stylish/), [IE?](https://superuser.com/questions/305105/equivalent-to-stylish-plug-in-for-ie-9); [quickstart](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251473/new-beta-style-is-much-harder-on-my-eyes-looking-for-css-overrides-to-fix), [detailed explanations](https://superuser.com/questions/234952/understanding-css-for-user-styling-in-a-browser/465964#465964)), you can make that field narrower.

```
@-moz-document domain("stackoverflow.com") {
    /* Shorten e.g. "Developer Jobs" to "Jobs" */
    a#nav-jobs {
        width: 3em !important;
        direction: rtl !important;
        overflow: hidden !important;
    }
}
```

(A multi-word title is a really bad idea here: it looks like “Developer” and “Jobs” are separate menus. Yes, I did wonder for a moment what the “Developer” menu was for. Yes, I know your A/B testing told you that you get more clicks on the wider text, so “Developer Jobs” is scientifically superior and I should be glad that it isn't blinking and dancing the rumba.)