# Change the tab name and page title of the "jobs search" tab

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

The tab as well as the page title of the [jobs search](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab) says "Developer Jobs" but it already contains offers for positions like project manager, or SW tester. Wouldn't be better to call it like "IT Jobs" or so?

Comment: how about the old _Jobs_

Comment: @Sagar, I'm not a big fan of those _thin_ tabs, but _Tags_ is already short. You can hardly describe the real content "behind" (_Jobs_, _Job Search_, _IT Jobs_ or e.g. _Job Offers_ can still be mislead with [We're hiring!](https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here) site, so even _Jobs_ could describe the real content better than _Developer Jobs_).

Answer (score 9):

We recently ran a [multivariant test](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350575/jobs-tab-title-is-dynamically-changing-it-is-for-a-b-testing-or-else) of different titles for the tab.

To our surprise, "Developer Jobs" was driving a lot more traffic to the jobs search page, much more than any other of the alternatives tested.

Given this result, we have decided to use "Developer Jobs" as a new baseline before we start testing other variations (we want to let any novelty effect to somewhat wear off first).

You are correct in that there are jobs that are not strictly "Developer Jobs" listed, but you know - Stack Overflow *visitors* are much more likely to be developers than project managers or SW testers, and that's the main group we are serving.

Comment: ... this does have the disadvantage of making the top bar ***ridiculously*** cramped for moderators. "Search" anyone https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PLXm.png?

Comment: @Matt - we are aware of the issue (after all, many Stack Exchange employees - developers and CMs are also moderators). I can tell you that the designer was not pleased that the *longest* possible variation won...

Comment: @Matt Good thing the search box has the disorienting "zoom" feature, then! Oh wait, I think I'm using that word "good" wrong.

Comment: I would click that even if it said _Search Jobs_. About the page title, wouldn't some 'search term' separator be handsome? I know who cares about [page titles](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&q=Nasty) these days :)